# Downloading and Naming Video With HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html5 video element on my page,

```
<video id="video" src="blah.mp4"></video>
```

I've attempted to add a download feature that allows the user to download the video with its respective title without requiring anything on the server to rename the file. I tried using the html5 download attribute.

```
<a href="blah.mp4" download="Introduction.mp4">Download</a>
```

It downloads the file, but it fails to properly name it with the title I give it and remains with the original title. I'm wondering if there is anyway to rename the file on the client's side.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have old browser? 
Check list of browsers which supports attribute 'download'
http://caniuse.com/download

Comment: hmmm... I press F12 on these page and type document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" download="introduction.mp4"> Download </a>' and file with name 'introduction.mp4' downloaded.